# Run Python script without activating virtual environment

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface

I want to run a python script from the command line but I'd like to eliminate the need to activate the virtual environment first. If possible, I'd also like to eliminate the need to call python before the script. I saw somewhere that adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the start of the script will work but I haven't been able to do so.

Comment: What does "I haven't been able to do so" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `chmod +x script.py` to make your script executable. The `#!shebang` selects an interpreter.

You can call an executable from the shell like so:

```
/path/to/script.py
```

Or:

```
cd /path/to; ./script.py
```

Alternatively, you can put your script in one of the directories defined by `$PATH`, which will let you call it just like any other utility.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing a structure like this in your **home** folder

```
home
- <user_name>
-- project_name
--- env
--- main.py
```

Where **env** is your virtual environment, you can use a *shebang* like this:

```
#!env/bin/python
```

at the very beginning of your **main.py** file. Then you should make your file executable with:

```
chmod +x main.py
```

Now if you run your code (from `project_name` folder) with:

```
./main.py
```

The code contained in **main.py** will be executed.

If you want to be able to run **main.py** from a different location, you should use an absolute path in the *shebang*, like:

```
#!/absolute/path/to/bin/python
```

So it will be something like:

```
#!/home/<user_name>/project_name/env/bin/python
```